# OBS - Recording non active desktop workspace

Tags: workspaces, desktop-recording

Is it possible to record an inactive workspace from a screen recording software like OBS? For example, recording what is going on in workspace 1 if I am actually looking at workspace 2 on the screen.

I don't have a good grounding on how workspaces work in X.org, and if hidden workspaces are rendered at all, so I'm not sure if this is possible, but maybe someone with more knowledge can give more insights on this.